# ¿Qué fue antes: "carnaval" o "carnestolendas"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

El otro día descubrí que la palabra ***[carnestolendas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7cLBurq)*** se puede usar como sinónimo de ***[carnaval](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7bcNniL)***. Buscando ambas palabras en Ngram encuentro su frecuencia de uso desde 1750:

[image: Carnaval contra carnestolendas]

Según parece, en el siglo XVIII su uso era mayoritario, pero a partir de aproximadamente 1830 la palabra *carnaval* pasó a ser la de uso generalizado, imagino que por su facilidad de pronunciación con respecto a su "adversaria".

Pensaba que tal vez *carnestolendas* fuese una palabra más antigua en español, y *carnaval* una palabra importada que se fue abriendo paso poco a poco en el lenguaje. Encontré que tenía razón a medias:

- Carnaval: Del it. *carnevale*, haplología del ant. *carnelevare*, de carne 'carne<sup>1</sup>' y *levare* 'quitar'.
- Carnestolendas: Del lat. *caro, carnis* 'carne<sup>1</sup>' y *tollendus*, gerundivo de *tollĕre* 'quitar, retirar'.

Es decir, ambas palabras tienen la misma etimología, pero *carnaval* pasó antes por el italiano, mientras que *carnestolendas* vino directamente del latín. En lo que me equivocaba era en la antigüedad, dado que en el diccionario español-latín de Nebrija de 1495 ya aparecen ambas palabras:

[image: Carnaval y carnes tollendas]

Cabe pensar que una palabra que pasó antes por otro idioma entró más tarde en el idioma español que otra que vino directamente del latín, lo que explicaría que el uso de la segunda antes de 1750 fuera mayoritario. Pero ¿es esto así? ¿Realmente se usaba más "carnestolendas" que "carnaval" antes del siglo XVIII? ¿Entró "carnestolendas" en el idioma español antes que "carnaval"? ¿Se recomendaba de alguna forma el uso de "carnestolendas" por aquel entonces frente al uso de un extranjerismo?

Comment: En catalán se dice _carnestoltes_.

Comment: @fedorqui esa palabra me suena de haberla leído en algún cómic de Superlópez...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque en el diccionario de Nebrija se recoge la palabra *carnaval*, no existen apenas textos en el CORDE anteriores a 1600 que usen dicha palabra, lo que puede sugerir que su uso era mayoritariamente oral. Un ejemplo:

> *Ya, señor, os veo, mas poco provecho me viene de vuestra vista, y estoy enojada porque me contrahicistes en la comedia de carnaval.*
>
> Francisco Delicado, "La Lozana Andaluza", 1528 (España).

Sin embargo, veo casos de *carnestolendas* en textos hasta del siglo XI, cuando el idioma se parecía más al latín clásico que al español actual:

> *Facta carta in era MLXXV notum die dominico pro carnestollendas quando rege fuit in andiçanicu XIII kalendas marcias.*
>
> Anónimo, "Donación hecha por Ramiro I a Ato Galíndez, de varias heredades en Larrés, en la era 1075", 1037 (España).

Este texto prueba que *carnestolendas* (o sus variantes *carnestollendas* o *carnestolliendas*, o incluso *carnestultas* según la región) ya existían en el latín vulgar. Un ejemplo de algo que más se parece al castellano:

> *El qui toviere bues o bestias, o bue o bestia con que omne pueda labrar, de carnestolliendas fata sant Andrés, quanto tiempo quequier que lo tenga, dé fuero por ello assí cuemo si lo toviesse tod'el año.*
>
> Anónimo, "Carta de don Miguel, abad de Oña", 1237 (España).

La palabra *carnevale* en italiano también proviene del latín vulgar, en su caso de *carne-levamen*, con transposición de las consonantes por influencia del latín *vale* ("adiós"). El hecho de que al español llegara ya la palabra *carnaval* con las consonantes traspuestas indicaría que primero debió transcurrir el tiempo suficiente como para que la palabra consiguiera su forma actual en italiano, por lo que la palabra *carnaval* debió llegar más tarde a nuestro idioma que *carnestolendas*. La falta de textos conteniendo *carnaval* anteriores al siglo XVI parece confirmarlo.